# Bulk update in subset obtained from dataframe filtering

Tags: r, subset

I have a dataframe, which I filter based on 2 condition as follow:

```
subset(sales_data, month == 'Jan' & dept_name == 'Production')`
```

I want to bulk update the value of a particular column(let's say `status`) of above subset 
Something like

```
subset(sales_data, month == 'Jan' & dept_name == 'Production')["status"] <- "Good result"`
```

I am not sure, how I can do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do

```
sales_data$status[
 sales_data$month == 'Jan' & sales_data$dept_name == 'Production'] <- "Good result"
```

Using `replace`

```
sales_data$status <- with(sales_data, 
     replace(status, month == 'Jan' & dept_name == 'Production', "Good result"))
```

---

We can also integrate this in `dplyr` chain.

```
library(dplyr)

sales_data %>%
   mutate(status = replace(status, month == 'Jan' & dept_name == 'Production', 
                   "Good result"))
```

or with `case_when`

```
sales_data %>%
 mutate(status = case_when(month == 'Jan' & dept_name =='Production'~"Good result",
                           TRUE ~ status))
```

`subset` filter the dataframe based on conditions provided and does not update them.